# Moving back webpages with Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-history

Ok this is the issue. I am working in a popup. We go from Page 1 to Page 2. Page 2 has frames set up on it. I know it's bad but it was not my decisions. Now on Page 2 in one frame we continue onto Page 3. If I click the back button on Page 2 with javascript history.go(-1) we can get to Page 1. But if the user goes from Page 2 to Page 3 then back to Page 2 a user can not simple go back to Page 1 unless the javascript is history.go(-3). Is there a way I can tell where I am coming from so I can determine which go to use?

FYI URLRefferrer does not work but it only gives me the page holding all the frames. Any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to link to the page you want directly instead of using `history.go`. Alternatively, you can try to use `parent.history.go(-1)`.

A third thing you may try, if you have complete control over all the links in the inner frame is to always use `location.replace` from the inner frame, which will not add an entry into the history, something like the following script

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.replace(this.href);
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem with linking directly is that there is data held on that previous page. If I link directly to it the data disappears. I will try the alternative though

Comment: So where would I add that. Would it be with the code that takes me to page 3?

Comment: @cjohnson2136: In every page that can go into the inner frame, so include it as an external script. So yes, the code that takes you to page 3, but you must remember that this is a JS solution that won't work in browsers with JS disabled, and that you need jQuery. If you create any dynamic links after the page has loaded, you need to make sure they are also using location.replace

Comment: That is not a problem because this is for a company. 90% of the website uses javascript because of UltraWebGrids. So that is not an issue about users having javascript on

Comment: I didn't go with your answer. I just kept getting errors. I found out that this website uses cookies so I am simple storing either -1 or -3 in a cookie and using that cookie to determine where the page is coming from.