# JavaScript: history.back() in two frames on the same web page

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser-history

I want to add a back button in each of the two frames of a web page
after some research I used this code:

```
<button onclick="parent.frames.frame_1.history.back();">Back</button>
```

But, after I click on something, for example a link on frame_1, and I click something else on frame_2, then I click my back button in frame_1, the code in the onClick event is executed in the frame_2 and not frame_1!

so can I add a back button to both of my frames without one affecting the other?

Comment: did you try just `window.history.back()` in your frame button?

Answer (score 0):

See this thread

[Moving back webpages with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738384/moving-back-webpages-with-javascript/9738441#9738441)

The OP on that question said that `parent.frames[index].history.back(0)` does not work. But from what I remember it works in some browsers but not all

Comment: I think that I should give up

Comment: @Skiller  What do you mean, "It's not working"? That's what my answer says: "It doesn't work". I posted it as an answer because I'm fairly confident it can't be done!

Comment: Sorry I thought it works only in some browsers so I tested it on: IE, FireFox and Chrome. Now I give up, I will not waste my time on such a functionnality...Thanks for your help.